# Background Audio Player: not working on device

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the Background Audio Player without success. The application works perfectly in the emulator but not on a Nokia Lumia 800. I've read the whole thread at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/394de7c4-4334-46f8-a01a-30b49c6ec242/ but this is not a codec issue.

What am I doing? I create an AudioTrack object with a remote server source URI and set it to the BAP instance. Then I call Play(). The player's state is going to "Playing" but no sound on the device.

What did I did to ensure that this is not a codec issue? I updated the code described above to first download the whole file from the remote server source URI and save it to the isolated storage. Then I created an AudioTrack object with the local file URI and got sound.

So, I suspect this is a buffering issue, as my player never change its state to BufferingStarted nor BufferingStopped. But, unfortunately, I don't know what I can do to help on this.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Fabian

Comment: I wonder of you are connected to the network via WIFI and somehow the connection is poor?

Comment: I tried while the device is connected to the LAN (while in debug) and over my company Wi-Fi (54 Mbps) and over 3G without any success.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a simple version of the XAP pointing to that resource and i try that on my Nokia Lumia 800. If that fails then we can look into the code? Or, have you tested on another Lumia already?

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately I can't share the XAP nor the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article about that kind of problem: http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2012/09/wp75-backgroundaudioplayer-crashes/